# Rally App SDK 2.0 - filter by date

Tags: rally, appsdk2

Is it possible to build a wsapi.Filter to filter out iterations based on StartDate and EndDate? I want to do something like

```
{
  property: 'StartDate',
  operator: '>=',
  value: myStartDate
}
```

or

```
{
  property: 'EndDate',
  operator: '<=',
  value: myEndDate
}
```

but it doesn't seem to be working. I can't even figure out how to manually query the iterations on the Web Services API page; I'm not sure how to format the date string properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this code that filters by StarDate within the last 90 days. Please see the output in the console:

```
Ext.define('CustomApp', { extend: 'Rally.app.App', componentCls: 'app',

        launch: function() {

        this.loadIterations(); 
        },

loadIterations: function() {
        var millisecondsInDay = 86400000;            
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var startDate = new Date(currentDate - millisecondsInDay*90);
        var startDateUTC = startDate.toISOString();
        console.log('startDateUTC',startDateUTC);
        console.log('startDate',startDate);
        var iterations = Ext.create('Rally.data.WsapiDataStore', {
            model: 'Iteration',
            autoLoad: true,
            fetch: ['ObjectID', 'Name', 'StartDate', 'PlannedVelocity'],
            filters:[
                {
                        property: 'StartDate',
                        operator: '>=',
                        value: startDateUTC
                }
            ],
            sorters: [
                {property: 'StartDate', direction: 'ASC'}
            ],
            listeners: {
                load: function(store, data, success) {
                    Ext.Array.each(data, function(record) {
                        console.info('ID: ', record.get('ObjectID'), 
                            '  Name: ', record.get('Name'),                             
                            '  StartDate: ', record.get('StartDate'), 
                            '  PlannedVelocity: ', record.get('PlannedVelocity'));
                    });
                }, scope: this
            }
        });        
}    
});
```

Comment: Ah, the .toISOString() was what I was missing. That got me to a point where I could actually query using the WebService API page, and also fixed my app at the same time. Thanks!